# Mistake on equation 9.75 PRML of CM Bishop?

Tags: machine-learning

On the denominator of equation 9.75, should not be the position of the productory and sumamtory exchanged?

[Posterior probability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px7al.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the equation is correct, but you also have a point,
in the sense that in this particular instance you can swap the sum and product:

$$
\sum_\mathbf{Z} \prod_{n=1}^N p(\mathbf{x}_n, \mathbf{z}_n | \mathbf{\theta}) = \prod_{n=1}^N \sum_{\mathbf{z}_n} p(\mathbf{x}_n, \mathbf{z}_n | \mathbf{\theta}).
$$

Here is a proof sketch:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_\mathbf{Z} \prod_{n=1}^N p(\mathbf{x}_n, \mathbf{z}_n | \mathbf{\theta}) &= \sum_{\mathbf{z_1}} \cdots \sum_{\mathbf{z_N}} \prod_{n=1}^N p(\mathbf{x}_n, \mathbf{z}_n | \mathbf{\theta}) \\
                                          &= \sum_{\mathbf{z_1}} \cdots \sum_{\mathbf{z_N}} p(\mathbf{x_1}, \mathbf{z_1} | \mathbf{\theta}) \cdots p(\mathbf{x_N}, \mathbf{z_N} | \mathbf{\theta}) \\
                                          &= \sum_{\mathbf{z_1}} p(\mathbf{x_1}, \mathbf{z_1} | \mathbf{\theta}) \cdots \sum_{\mathbf{z_N}} p(\mathbf{x_N}, \mathbf{z_N} | \mathbf{\theta}) \\
                                          &= \prod_{n=1}^N \sum_{\mathbf{z}_n} p(\mathbf{x}_n, \mathbf{z}_n | \mathbf{\theta}).
\end{aligned}
$$